# How to calculate confusion matrix for a training model ? (from this code)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, chatbot

how to calculate confusion matrix for this training model?

```
    model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2,
          verbose=1)
    model.summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have train and test sets and that `y_true` hold expected results:

1. train your model
2. store your predicted values in variable `y_predicted`
3. import confusion_matrix from sklear (`from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix`)
4. execute `confusion_matrix(y_true, y_predicted)`
5. Have fun in tuning your model ;)

Comment: please define which as y_true and y_predicted from my code snippet.
================================================


model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=epochs,
      validation_split=0.2,
      verbose=1)


model.summary()

Comment: @rzr Please, do *not* use the comments space for posting code - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your question if necessary, but here you are simply reposting the code from your question, which is useless...

Comment: @rzr I recommend you to take a look at some tutorials which might help you - to understand splitting into train/[validation or test] set (and explaining what they are) because I think that you train your model on whole training set and if you want to build confusion matrix on data which was used in training it might give you some misleading results. Here you have nice tutorials about Keras - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzoh8cfnvnI&list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrwRnXk_yCPtnqqo4_u2YGL&index=5 or if you want to understand a bit more what happen behind the hood you may take a look at Andrew Ng ML course.